# Measuring the prediction accuracy for the tensorflow-lite android version

Tags: android, tensorflow, prediction, horizontal-accuracy

I am using the tensorflow-lite version (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/java/demo). Can anyone please tell me how to compute the object detection accuracy or prediction accuracy runtime against novel images while using this?

It will be also better to know how to find the accuracy against the original source training/validation data set?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy of a custom `.tflite` model can be measured using the [TFLite accuracy tool](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/accuracy/ilsvrc).

If you are using the mobilenet_v1_1.0_224 version (as [defined in the demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/java/demo/app/src/main/BUILD)), then you can check out its accuracy on the [hosted models](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models) page. For V1, the top-5 accuracy is ~89.9%